# jQuery: get elements of css classes that extends certain class

Tags: jquery, css

I have a class in css for some input text. I have two more class which extends from the first class, like this:

```
    .input-text-parent {
         background-color: gray;
    }

    .input-text-child-1 {
         extends: input-text-parent;
         background-image: url(images/image1.jpg);
    }

    .input-text-child-2 {
         extends: input-text-parent;
         background-image: url(images/image2.jpg);
    }
```

Now, what I want to do is to select with jQuery all the elements that extends the first class (input-text-parent, in this case).
I know that with $(".class") I can get all the elements of that class, but I don't know how to get all it's subclasses.

Thank you very much.

I hope I was clear enough in my explanation.

Comment: In css the `extends` property doesn't exist, and therefore does nothing (except, perhaps, generate errors in any validator). Is this LESS or SASS?

Comment: But you could use two classes for complex elements rather than extending one, that'd solve the problem pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend refactoring your css to use two classes for complex elements instead of one that extends another, which accomplishes esentially the same thing except no preprocessing is needed. For instance:

```
.input-text {
     background-color: gray;
}

.input-text.child-1 {
     background-image: url(images/image1.jpg);
}

.input-text.child-2 {
     background-image: url(images/image2.jpg);
}
```

You could then use the following markup:

```
<div class="input-text"></div>
<div class="input-text child-1"></div>
<div class="input-text child-2"></div>
```

And the following javascript via jQuery:

```
$(".input-text").stuff(); //Select all of them
$(".input-text.child-1").stuff(); //Select only child-1
```

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hierarchy of sub-casses in CSS and you can't select all elements beginning with a specific name of classes.

But you can :

Select all elements with a specific class :

```
$('.input-text-parent').each(function(){
    //Do something
});
```

Or select all elements with specific classes

```
$('.input-text-parent .input-text-parent-1').each(function(){
    //Do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't have anything built in specifically for this because css doesn't really have sub class support. each of those "sub classes" are really just completely separate classes that happen to have similar names.

jQuery's `filter` method combined with the `className` property should be able to select the elements with a class of `input-text-child-n`

```
$("input").filter(function(){
    return this.className.indexOf("input-text-child-") >= 0;
}).doSomething();
```